# Google Cloud Storage network usage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am using GCS to store images for my Android application.
I was searching the Google Cloud Platform console, but haven't found network usage or something that will show me how many people uploaded/downloaded how many files/bytes of data. They tell you how they [calculate the price](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing), using network and class a/b operations, but i don't find the place to track this data myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to export these logs to bigquery. You can't find them in GCP interface

> Storage logs are generated once a day and contain the storage usage for the previous day. They are typically created before 10:00 am PST.
>
> Usage logs are generated hourly when there is activity to report in the monitored bucket. Usage logs are typically created 15 minutes after the end of the hour.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs

Comment: Thanx. That is not user friendly at all.